# Username and password shown as plain text on network tab of developer tools

Tags: angular

I have an angular application that implemented a login screen that accepts username and password and passing that info to my endpoint. Below is my endpoint code.

I can see the username and password on the network tab of developertools. Could somebody tell me what the problem .Why isnt it getting encoded and displayed as plain text . What is the best practice to hide such sensitive information

```
getLoginEndpoint<T>(userName: string, password: string): Observable<T> {

        let header = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });

        let params = new HttpParams()
            .append('username', userName)
            .append('password', password)
            .append('grant_type', 'password')
            .append('scope', 'openid email phone profile offline_access roles')
            .append('resource', window.location.origin);

        let requestBody = params.toString();

        return this.http.post<T>(this.loginUrl, requestBody, { headers: header });
    }
```

Comment: This is normal, the browser knows everything you post over the net. To prevent eavesdropping configure https on your web server

Comment: So you mean just by configuring it to Https, it wont show up ?

Comment: @Tom, It'll still show up, but it will make MITM attacks much more difficult since it will be encrypted in-flight.

Answer (score 0):

Encoding is different than encryption.

Looks like you're sending `password` as is (which is, in fact, shown in your network inspector tab)

Like @basin mentioned - you can enable https to prevent MITM attack.

You may also hash the `password` as a string to ensure plaintext password does not travel over network.